# Objectify query by raw datastore Key

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I'm having trouble with understanding the upgrade process from JDO to Objectify.

So I have this class:

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class AppUser { 
    /**
     * key from userID
     */
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent
    private Key key;

    //...
}
```

And I upgraded it to:

```
@Entity
public class AppUser { 
    /**
     * key from userID
     */
    @Index Key key;
    @Id Long id;

    // ...
}
```

Before the change I was able to retrieve the entity using following method:

```
Key _key = KeyFactory.createKey(AppUser.class.getSimpleName(), user.getUserId());
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
AppUser appUser = pm.getObjectById(AppUser.class, _key);
```

Where `user` object is AppEngine's user object referenced with Google Account.

How can I query for an entity for given user? When I try to use `filterKey` it results with null object.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Currently your `key` attribute is just an indexed attribute, therefor you should be able to query for it with

```
ofy().load().type(AppUser.class).filter("key", Key.create(AppUser.class, id)).list();
```

I get the feeling that this is not what you're looking for since you don't have an `id` **and** a `key` property in your above code sample. Also the Key property would be a reference to another entity which i don't see in your first code sample. So i assume that you really only want to use the id. Now i don't know whether your key is numeric or a string, but i assume you're looking for something like this:

```
@Entity
public class AppUser { 
    @Id Long key; // you can replace Long with String if your ids are strings
}
```

You would then query by id, like so

```
ofy().load().type(AppUser.class).id(userIdOrName).list();
```

alternatively a key query would look like this

```
ofy().load().key(Key.create(AppUser.class, userIdOrName));
```

Comment: It's not necessarily what I'm looking for. My old API used raw keys to look for an entity. Now, however, when I'm trying to query for a key using `filterKey` of `ofy()` object it returns null. I tried different values: key as before, new numeric ID, old string ID, Ref<?>, Key<?> and Key object. Nothing works. Eventually I stopped working on it since there are more important things to do right now. But I'll come back to this issue sooner or later because API change in inveritable in my case.

Comment: You only define a `Key` using Objectify when it's a reference to a different entity. The key of the entitiy itself is implicitly created when you define a property with the `@Id` annotation. Maybe you could describe a bit more what you're trying to do on a high level. Something that should also help is what your raw key looks like. Most key representations can be converted to different representations so you might have to do a key conversion before you can query with objectify.